# In a specified folder, how can I recursively delete everything except ".mkv" and ".nfo" files?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I'm trying to figure out the code for a batch-file (Windows) that *In a specified folder recursively deletes everything except files with a certain extension (i.e. `.mkv` and `.nfo`)?*

Something like this, but for the above.

```
def deleteRootFolder = tryQuietly{ root.toBoolean() }

/*
 * Delete orphaned "clutter" files like nfo, jpg, etc and sample files
 */
def isClutter(f) {
    def exts    = tryQuietly{ exts }            ?: /jpg|jpeg|png|gif|nfo|xml|htm|html|log|srt|sub|idx|md5|sfv|txt|rtf|url|db|dna|log/
    def terms   = tryQuietly{ terms }           ?: /sample|trailer|extras|deleted.scenes|music.video|scrapbook/
    def maxsize = tryQuietly{ maxsize as Long } ?: 100 * 1024 * 1024

    // path contains blacklisted terms or extension is blacklisted
    return (f.extension ==~ "(?i)($exts)" || f.path =~ "(?i)\\b($terms)\\b") && f.length() < maxsize
}


def clean(f) {
    println "Delete $f"

    // do a dry run via --action test
    if (_args.action == 'test') {
        return false
    }

    return f.isDirectory() ? f.deleteDir() : f.delete()
}


// delete clutter files in orphaned media folders
args.getFiles{ isClutter(it) && !it.dir.hasFile{ (it.isVideo() || it.isAudio()) && !isClutter(it) }}.each { clean(it) }

// delete empty folders but exclude given args
args.getFolders().sort().reverse().each { if (it.listFiles().length == 0) { if (deleteRootFolder || !args.contains(it)) clean(it) } }
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows.

Comment: This is not batch, what are you looking for?

Comment: We'll I use SABnzbd that has a blacklist function for extensions(otherwise know as a cleanup list), but no whitelist function. Unfortunately the list of what you don't want(blacklist) is unlimited, and the list of what you do want(whitelist) is ofted times only two(or so) depending on the category. So I'm looking for some batch-code that will "In a specified folder recursively delete everything except for a list of extensions ie .mkv .nfo"

Comment: @DavidCuster I could suggest you a simple Bash script for Linux, but I'm not that expert on CLI commands for Windows.

Comment: I should be using linux. Windows just has different desktop programs. Linux is best for a server ;) And desktop lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one quick way of doing this among many:

```
@echo off
set extlist=mkv nfo
set rootfolder="C:\Video Folder"
pushd %rootfolder%
if not ["%cd%"]==[%rootfolder%] echo Aborting as unable to change to %rootfolder% && goto End
attrib /s /d -r
for %%a in (%extlist%) do attrib /s *.%%a +r
del. /s /q
:End
popd
```

Run on a test dir first with a few files that you want to retain and others you want to delete, before unleashing on your main dir. If you want the batch file to request delete confirmation for every file, change `del. /s /q` to `del. /s /p`.

Comment: If you want to get rid of empty dirs as well, then before the `:End` line insert the following (*rd* doesn't normally delete non-empty dirs): `for /r %%a in (.) do rd "%%~a"`.

Comment: YOU ARE AMAZING! Karan is my hero, he has saved me in other posts as well.

Comment: I added the deletion of non-empty dirs per your tutorial. PERFECT!

Answer (score 1):

this is an other way without the need to change attributes, look at the output & remove `echo`, if OK:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "extlist=.mkv|.nfo|"
for /r "c:\video" %%i in (*) do (
    set "fname=%%~i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    if "!extlist:%%~xi|=!"=="%extlist%" echo del "!fname!"
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: ;) Your the best! Are you saying this is a better way? In your opinion?

Comment: If you change the attributes to _read only_ you must set it back after deleting the other files (otherwise all MKV/NFO will stay _read only_). And you can't use the attributes for other things because the previous state is not restored.

Comment: It doesn't actually delete anything. Hmmmm.

Comment: Yes, you must remove the word `echo` before.......

Comment: LOLOLOL OOps -.-

Comment: All it takes is one additional `attrib /s -r` to remove the read-only attributes. Personally I like +R for my videos, because one of my media streamers has a tendency to update metatags with incorrect data from the net and ruin my carefully entered tags. Anyway, I really like how Endoro has implemented this using substring replacement. David, I can see you unaccepted my answer when this was posted and then perhaps thought about it and re-accepted it 5s later. Feel free to accept this one; one is always permitted to change one's mind! :)